# ActiveMQ - any way to disconnect another client based on the client ID?

Tags: php, activemq-classic

I am using Amazon MQ which is a managed Active MQ instance. I am connecting over STOMP with PHP using this [stomp-php library](https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php). I plan on having these listeners running continuously, and if disconnected, reconnect. My concern is that for some reason or another, a script will stop working but the client won't disconnect. If this happens, I wouldn't be able to reconnect with that client ID until the other client disconnects.

If this happens, I want to be able to close the connection remotely. I don't know if this is possible with STOMP though, I don't see anything about it in the STOMP documentation. It seems that once you connect through STOMP, you're connecting as a client and everything you do is in relation to that client.

I looked at the ActiveMQ documentation and I see in Artemis (IDK if AmazonMQ is Artemis or Classic) there's a [closeConnectionWithClientID](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-1.0.0/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/jms/management/JMSServerControl.html#closeConnectionWithClientID-java.lang.String-) JMSServerControl method. This seems like it's exactly what I want to do, but through STOMP or some other way via PHP.

Does anyone know how I would go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AmazonMQ is based on ActiveMQ "classic" 5.x versions.  Via the STOMP client there isn't a way to forcibly disconnect another client, there isn't a way through any of the client protocols as that'd be a horrendous security and usability issue.

To remove a client you need to use the JMX management APIs in 5.x which I'm nut sure are exposed in AmazonMQ instances but that'd be the place to start looking.  In 5.x the JMX API can be exposed using Jolokia such that an HTTP request could be used to invoke them once you has established authentication and authorization to the admin role you hopefully have configured.

Comment: I guess according to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=833020#833020), AmazonMQ does not currently support JMX access. It's odd because even in their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/api-reference/amazon-mq-api.pdf#page=25) for their API, it mentions that actions made on JMX are logged in cloudwatch.

I suppose for now the only way to get rid of these stagnant connections through AmazonMQ would be to reboot the broker altogether.

Comment: Another option is to configure the broker to enforce heart beats on STOMP connections even if using older clients that don't request it: https://activemq.apache.org/stomp